# How to extract json Response?

Tags: json

Someone told me.

obj is a JSON response.

```
obj =　{ title: 'ABCD', _key: '-KX9Cwwuc2FjxcG-SNY0' }
```

I can get ABCD using console.log(obj["title”]).

How about complex case?

```
obj = { '-KXu3irrOjUtcejm4VF3': 
   { gold: 0,
     title: ‘xxxx09x@gmail.com',
     uketuke: 0,
    user: ‘xxxx09x@gmail.com' },
  '-KXu3vLo7--JeVYC9fJa': { title: ‘JUMP' },
  '-KXu3yRZgFlDcS8BZ7e1': { title: 'JUMP1' } }
```

In this case, how can I get the user entity?

By the way like this obj["title”] presentation, I think this should be ECMA standard,
please let me know where reference is?

Answer (score 0):

**If you knew the key** then it's quite easy. For example:

```
obj = { 
    '-KXu3irrOjUtcejm4VF3': { 
        gold: 0,
        title: 'xxxx09x@gmail.com',
        uketuke: 0,
        user: 'xxxx09x@gmail.com' 
    },
    '-KXu3vLo7--JeVYC9fJa': { title: 'JUMP' },
    '-KXu3yRZgFlDcS8BZ7e1': { title: 'JUMP1' } 
}

var user_key = '-KXu3irrOjUtcejm4VF3'

user = obj[user_key].user
```

> "xxxx09x@gmail.com"

**However if you did not know the key** of object in which the user exists then the following function can help with asymptotic complexity O(n):

```
function getUser(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        // skip loop if the property is from prototype
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[key].user !== undefined) {
            return obj[key].user;
        }
    }
}

getUser(obj)
```

> "xxxx09x@gmail.com"

**And finally there is something I used in one of projects:** [jsonpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

```
$..user
```

would return all `user` from your obj. This way you can go quite far with a complicated json IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

**Need to do some corrections :**

To access the property value from this JSON response `var obj =　{ title: 'ABCD', _key: '-KX9Cwwuc2FjxcG-SNY0' }` you have to use `dot(.) operator` instead of `[]`.

If you will use `obj[title]` it will give you **an error :**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined(…)

If you will use `obj.title` it will give you **an output :**

`ABCD`

So, as per the **complex case :**

**First thing :** Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.

**Invalid JSON :**

```
var obj = { 
            '-KXu3irrOjUtcejm4VF3': { 
                                      gold: 0,
                                      title: 'xxxx09x@gmail.com',
                                      uketuke: 0,
                                      user: 'xxxx09x@gmail.com' 
                                    },
            '-KXu3vLo7--JeVYC9fJa': { title: ‘JUMP' },
            '-KXu3yRZgFlDcS8BZ7e1': { title: 'JUMP1' } 
          };
```

**Valid JSON :**

```
var obj = {
    "-KXu3irrOjUtcejm4VF3": {
        "gold": 0,
        "title": "abc@gmail.com",
        "uketuke": 0,
        "user": "def@gmail.com"
    },
    "-KXu3vLo7--JeVYC9fJa": {
        "title": "JUMP"
    },
    "-KXu3yRZgFlDcS8BZ7e1": {
        "title": "JUMP1"
    }
}
```